# pandas groupby and do categorical ordering to drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Name": ["Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim",'Jack','Jack','Jack'],
        "Status": ["A1", "E1", "B3", "D4", "C90","A1","C90","B3"]
})
```

The actual order of my status variable is B3 < A1 < D4 < C90 < E1.

So the last value is E1 and 1st value is B3.

I would like to do the below

a) groupby `Name`

a) order the values based on categorical ordering shown above

c) Keep only the last value (after dropping duplicates based on `Name` column)

So, I tried the below

```
df["Status"] = df["Status"].astype("category")
df["Status"] = df["Status"].cat.set_categories(["B3", "A1", "D4", "C90", "E90"], ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values(['Status'])
df_cleaned = df.drop_duplicates(['Status'],keep='last')
```

But this results in incorrect output.

I expect my output to be like as below (one row for each `Name` and their latest/last `Status` value)

```
Name   Status
Tim     E1
Jack    C90
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add existing categories to list and sorting with remove duplicates by `Name` column:

```
df["Status"] = pd.Categorical(df["Status"], 
                              categories=["B3", "A1", "D4", "C90", "E90","E1"], 
                              ordered=True)

df_cleaned = (df.sort_values(['Status'])
                .drop_duplicates(['Name'],keep='last')

print (df_cleaned)
   Name Status
6  Jack    C90
1   Tim     E1
```

If possible some values are not in list of categories also remove missing values:

```
df_cleaned = (df.dropna(subset=['Status'])
                .sort_values(['Status'])
                .drop_duplicates(['Name'],keep='last')
```

Comment: @TheGreat - Honestly no idea if exist some way without try it.

Comment: I create answer, for linked solution need change `df1 = df.set_index('key')` and `df1.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1, sort=False)`

Answer (score 2):

You can abstract the category column creation with [encode_categorical](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.encode_categorical.encode_categorical) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), and either use `drop_duplicates` or `groupby`:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df
.encode_categorical(Status=['B3', 'A1', 'D4','C90','E1'])
.sort_values(['Name','Status'])
# you can skip the lines below with drop_duplicates
# .drop_duplicates(subset='Name', keep='last')
.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
.Status
.last()
) 
   Name Status
0  Jack    C90
1   Tim     E1
```

Comment: good to know about this janitor package